# opening a new tab by selecting from options html

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, tags

I'm currently using < select > tags and < option > tags each with their own value attributes and using it link to a new page.

This is my code:

```
                <div class="label">
                <label> Select your online bank login:  &nbsp;</label>
                <select id="selectBank">
                    <option value="https://ipn.paymentus.com/epd/stde/lhud"> Paymentus </option>
                    <option value="https://www12.bmo.com/onlinebanking/cgi-bin/netbnx/NBmain"> BMO </option>
                    <option value="https://www.myvisaaccount.com/Vancity_Consumer/Login.do"> Citizens' Bank of Canada </option>
                    <option value="https://bvi.bnc.ca/auth/Login"> National Bank of Canada </option>
                </select>

                <button onclick="goToBankLogin()"> Login </button>
```

and this is the javascript code for selecting values, right now it opens into a new page:

```
 function goToBankLogin() {
        var selectedBank = selectBank.options[selectBank.options.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location.replace(selectedBank.toString());
    }
```

and i need it to open to a new tab, how would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just playing around and figured this out, it works for me and opens up a new tab

changed up my function a bit:

```
    function goToBankLogin() {
        var selectedBank = selectBank.options[selectBank.options.selectedIndex].value;
        window.open(selectedBank.toString());
    }
```

Comment: yep, it did, i can provide a demo too if u want

Comment: Yeah sure, also, accept your own asnwer as when others come to your questions they will see how it got handled.

Comment: yep, sure, it will let me do that in 2 days